# fast performance when reading multiple *.gif images

Tags: r, gif

My computer (i5-6500 3.2 GHZ, 8 GB RAM) takes a long time: something like 10 minutes (havent yet measured exactly).

i currently have to

1. read 400 images. (*.gif format, should all be b&w, resolution of approx. 200*400 px.)   (3520 images in total)
2. i want to "add" all images "cell-wise".

here is how im doing it at the moment: Read image with `raster` than turn it into `matrix`, then `sum` it.

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(magrittr)

oldPic <- raster("initalImage.gif") %>% as.matrix

for (pat_IND in currSide) {
    newPic <- raster(pat_IND) %>% as.matrix
    oldPic <- oldPic + newPic
}
```

This takes for ever. I used `caTools::read.gif()` which was even much slower. Do i have a bottle neck in my code? Is there a faster implementation?

## Edit: Image Properties

[image]

i use "no dither", mono palette (b&w).

## Edit2

i want to add the images pixel-wise. Lets take pic A and pic B.

A + B = C. If A(1,1) = 1 and B(1,1) = 1, C(1,1) should be 2. Its a simple matrix addition.

test image:

[image: img]

1. reading with raster takes 0.03699994 secs
2. reading with raster + as.matrix takes: 0.201 secs

Comment: not sure what are the times of ... by #1 you mean decoding time of GIF  and by #2 decoding time of GIF + conversion from raster to matrix ? if yes then booth times are too big  (5 times bigger then mine GIF loader probably not well optimized loader) but it looks like the matrix stuff is your problem try to write the conversion your self ... also check the data type of your matrix if it is floating point there may be the problem use integers if you can so you do not need to convert so much ...

Comment: 1. its the time r takes to read the GIF-file and create a raster object. "as matrix" makes it 6 times slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to measure... without any sample image is hard to say and we can only guess. You need to take into account that loading/decoding **JPG** take time in milliseconds and encoding of **GIF** can be time consuming even `200 ms`.  Depends on kind of encoding. To speed up **GIF** encoding you can:

1. **use single global palette + dithering**

   **GIF** is `8 bpp`  and **JPG** is `24 bpp` so your encoder needs to do the transformation. That is called color quantization and is the most expensive operation while encoding which can take even `~200 ms` per frame on average **PC** machine in well optimized **C++** code.  for more info see:

   - [Effective gif/image color quantization?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30265253/2521214)

   To remedy this you can use single palette dedicated to dithering (like default **VGA** or use some **WEB** palette they have the same purpose) and use dithering with is much much faster. See:

   - [simple and fast Dithering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36820654/2521214)

   btw if you need to preserve colors take a look at this:

   - [Images lose quality after saving as GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41283985/2521214)

   So try to find out how to configure your encoder to force dithering instead of color quantization based on **K-means** or similar ....
2. **limit encoding dictionary to less then `4096`**

   The encoding/decoding is based on creating dictionary and encoding need to search it more than once on per pixel basis. So lovering its size to `1024` gets significant boost to speed. Of coarse you need to access to encoding code to change this unless this can be configured somehow in it... The compression will be decreased by this however and more clear codes will be present in the stream.
3. **use multi-threading**

   you can fully parallelize this and encode with each core present in your system.

I strongly recommend you to measure how long it take to encode single frame of **GIF**. If you take advantage on both bullets **#1,#2** then I estimate you can get near times around `~5 ms` per frame with dithering and `~60 ms` per frame with fast quantization. So with `3520` frames it would take around `17.6` or `211.2` seconds just to encode **GIF** so add the file memory and **JPG** manipulation and take into account all is heavily guessed/estimated as you did not provide sample data. And divide by number of cores if you use **#3** `+/-` shared disc access waits.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think i will indeed, try to find a way to go parallel. My gifs are all b&w indexed with values 0-black and 1-white. i believe there is also an transparent layer. I believe the GIF format in it self is a bottle neck. Can you recommend a "faster" format for b&w images? so i can use it in the next project?

Comment: @AndreElrico with BW the color quantization should not be a problem but you should check it with color picker or something so you do not have 128 colors near white and 128 near black. Also you can set the number of colors to minimum I think 1 bpp is supported. GIF should be fast enough for this the only question is if your implementation is I do not use 3th party libs for GIFs as I got my own ... But you have to measure the times to be sure in this case may be the JPG is bad choice as it is not suited for BW images ... If you share few sample images I can measure so you have comparison times.

Comment: There is no JPG. I made a mistake in my post. They are all gifs with the above properties. I added a foto of my image properties, is this in a "fast" format?

Comment: @AndreElrico yes the format and config looks ok share at least one frame so I can measure how fast it will load. You may have another problem as you wrote you create matrix first and then sum it ... may be it is too large for your memory and swapping get involved ... Also by summing you mean creating single image or add a frame to result animation?

Comment: look in my question on "edit2". thank you for taking your time!

Comment: @AndreElrico OK I copied the image here on SO. the decoding (single thread pure SW on CPU side C++ 32 bit app) time of that **GIF** is `~7.5ms` on my setup (AMD A8-5500 APU 3.2GHz Win7 x64) file access included. the operation you are performing should take a fraction of that lets say 2.5ms per frame just to be safe so  `10ms per frame -> 32.500 sec`  If you got a lot bigger time you got a bottleneck somewhere so test how long you get to decode GIF and how long to add frame to your result. If your times varying too much from mine (scaled by your CPU power) then you should clearly see what part