# Understanding image dithering and how they help blending CSM

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shadow-mapping, dithering

So I wish to implement dithering as a blend mode between my cascade shadow map splits.

I had no idea what they were so I've watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nK6pYXRHTVU) to try and understand it.
As far as I understand it it's a way to map an image colors to a limited pallet while trying to maintain a convincing gradient between different colored pixels.

Now from this video I understand how to calculate what color my eye will see based on the weights of the dithering pattern. What I do not understand is how we take an image with 4 bytes pixels data and for example trying to map it to 1 byte pixel data. How can we map each pixel color in the original image to a dither pattern that it's weighted average will look as if it's the original color if we're basically limited? Say we were limited to only 5 colors, I'm guessing not every possible weighted average combination of dither pattern using these 5 pallet color could result in the original pixel color so how can this be achieved? Also is a dither pattern is calculated for each pixel to achieve a dithered image?

Besides these general question about image dithering I'm still having difficulties understanding how this technique is helping us blend between cascade splits, where as far as actually implementing it in code, I've seen an example where it uses the space coordinates of a fragment and calculate a dither (Not sure what it's calculating actually because it doesn't return a matrix it returns a float):

```
float GetDither2(ivec2 p)
{
    float d = 0.0;

    if((p.x & 1) != (p.y & 1))
        d += 2.0;
    if((p.y & 1) == 1)
        d += 1.0;

    d *= 0.25;

    return d;
}

float GetDither4(ivec2 p)
{
    float d = GetDither2(p);
    d = d * 0.25 + GetDither2(p >> 1);
    return d;
}

float threshold = GetDither4(ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy));

if(factor <= threshold)
{
    // sample current cascade
}
else
{
    // sample next cascade
}
```

And then it samples either cascade map based on this returned float.
So my brain can't translate what I learned that you can have a dither pattern to simulate large color pattern, into this example that uses a returned float as a threshold factor and compares it to some blend factor just to sample from either shadow map. So it made me more confused.

Would appreciate a good explanation of this

**EDIT:**

Ok I see correlation between the algorithm I was provided with to the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_dithering) about ordered dithering, which as far as I understand is the preferred dithering algorithm because according to the article:

> Additionally, because the location of the dithering patterns always
>   stays the same relative to the display frame, it is less prone to
>   jitter than error-diffusion methods, making it suitable for
>   animations.

Now I see the code tries to get this threshold value for a given space coordinate although it seems to me it got it a bit wrong because the following calculation of threshold is a follows:
`Mpre(i,j) = (Mint(i,j)+1) / n^2`

And it needs to set: `float d = 1.0` instead of `float d = 0.0` if Im not mistaken.
Secondly, I’m not sure how left shifting the `ivec2` space coordinate (I’m not even sure what’s the behavior of bitwise shift on vector in glsl…) but I assumes it just component bitwise operation, and I tried plug-in (head calculating) for a given space coordinate `(2,1)` (according to my assumptions about the bitwise operation) and got different threshold result for what should be the threshold value of this position in a 4x4 Bayer matrix.

So I'm skeptic about how well this code implements the ordered dithering algorithm.

Secondly I’m still not sure how this threshold value has anything to do with choosing between shadow map 1 or 2, and not just reducing color pallet of a given pixel, this logic hasn’t settled in my mind yet as I do not understand the use of dithering threshold value for a given space coordinate to choose the right map to sample from.

Lastly won’t choosing space coordinate will cause jitters? Given fragment in world position `(x,y,z)` who’s shadowed. Given this fragment space coordinate for a given frame are `(i,j)`. If the camera moves won’t this fragment space coordinate bound to change making the dither threshold calculated for this fragment change with each movement causing jitters of the dither pattern?

**EDIT2:**
Tried to blend the maps as follow although result not look so good any ideas?

```
const int indexMatrix8x8[64] = int[](
    0, 32, 8, 40, 2, 34, 10, 42,
    48, 16, 56, 24, 50, 18, 58, 26,
    12, 44, 4, 36, 14, 46, 6, 38,
    60, 28, 52, 20, 62, 30, 54, 22,
    3, 35, 11, 43, 1, 33, 9, 41,
    51, 19, 59, 27, 49, 17, 57, 25,
    15, 47, 7, 39, 13, 45, 5, 37,
    63, 31, 55, 23, 61, 29, 53, 21
);

for (int i = 0; i < NR_LIGHT_SPACE; i++) {
        if (fs_in.v_FragPosClipSpaceZ <= u_CascadeEndClipSpace[i]) {
            shadow = isInShadow(fs_in.v_FragPosLightSpace[i], normal, lightDirection, i) * u_ShadowStrength;
                int x = int(mod(gl_FragCoord.x, 8));
                int y = int(mod(gl_FragCoord.y, 8));
                float threshold = (indexMatrix8x8[(x + y * 8)] + 1) / 64.0;
                if (u_CascadeBlend >= threshold)
                {
                    shadow = isInShadow(fs_in.v_FragPosLightSpace[i + 1], normal, lightDirection, i + 1) * u_ShadowStrength;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Basically if I understand what I'm doing is getting the threshold value from the matrix for each space coordinate of a shadowed pixel and if it's (using probability) higher than a blend factor than I sample the second map instead.

Here're the results:
[image]
The larger red box is where the split between map occurs.

The smaller red box goes to show that there's some dither pattern but the image isn't so blended as I think it should.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I have no knowledge about CSM so I focus on dithering and blending. Firstly see these:

- [my very simple dithering in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36820654/2521214) I come up with
- [image dithering routine that accepts an amount of dithering?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36839144/2521214) and its variation

They basically answers you question about how to compute the dithering pattern/pixels.

Also its important to have good palette for dithering that reduce your 24/32 bpp  into 8 bpp (or less). There are 2 basic approaches

1. **reduce colors (color quantization)**

   so compute histogram of original image and pick significant colors from it that more or less cover whole image information. For more info see:

   - [Effective gif/image color quantization?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30265253/2521214)
2. **dithering palette**

   dithering use averaging of pixels to generate desired color so we need to have such colors that can generate all possible colors we want. So its good to have few (2..4) shades  of each base color (R,G,B,C,M,Y) and some (>=4) shades of gray. From these you can combine any color and intensity you want (if you have enough pixels)

**#1** is the best but it is per image related so you need to compute palette for each image. That can be problem as that computation is nasty CPU hungry stuff. Also on old 256 color modes you could not show 2 different palettes at the same time (which with true color is no more a problem anymore) so dithering is usually better choice.

You can even combine the two for impressive results.

The better the used palette is the less grainy the result is ...

The standard VGA 16 and 256 color palettes where specially designed for dithering so its a good idea to use them...

**Standard VGA 16 color palette:**
[image: VGA 16 colors]

**Standard VGA 256 color palette:**
[image: VGA 256 colors]

**Here also C++ code for the 256 colors:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- EGA VGA pallete -------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _vgapal_h
#define _vgapal_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
unsigned int vgapal[256]=
    {
    0x00000000,0x00220000,0x00002200,0x00222200,
    0x00000022,0x00220022,0x00001522,0x00222222,
    0x00151515,0x00371515,0x00153715,0x00373715,
    0x00151537,0x00371537,0x00153737,0x00373737,
    0x00000000,0x00050505,0x00000000,0x00030303,
    0x00060606,0x00111111,0x00141414,0x00101010,
    0x00141414,0x00202020,0x00242424,0x00202020,
    0x00252525,0x00323232,0x00303030,0x00373737,
    0x00370000,0x00370010,0x00370017,0x00370027,
    0x00370037,0x00270037,0x00170037,0x00100037,
    0x00000037,0x00001037,0x00001737,0x00002737,
    0x00003737,0x00003727,0x00003717,0x00003710,
    0x00003700,0x00103700,0x00173700,0x00273700,
    0x00373700,0x00372700,0x00371700,0x00371000,
    0x00371717,0x00371727,0x00371727,0x00371737,
    0x00371737,0x00371737,0x00271737,0x00271737,
    0x00171737,0x00172737,0x00172737,0x00173737,
    0x00173737,0x00173737,0x00173727,0x00173727,
    0x00173717,0x00273717,0x00273717,0x00373717,
    0x00373717,0x00373717,0x00372717,0x00372717,
    0x00372525,0x00372531,0x00372536,0x00372532,
    0x00372537,0x00322537,0x00362537,0x00312537,
    0x00252537,0x00253137,0x00253637,0x00253237,
    0x00253737,0x00253732,0x00253736,0x00253731,
    0x00253725,0x00313725,0x00363725,0x00323725,
    0x00373725,0x00373225,0x00373625,0x00373125,
    0x00140000,0x00140007,0x00140006,0x00140015,
    0x00140014,0x00150014,0x00060014,0x00070014,
    0x00000014,0x00000714,0x00000614,0x00001514,
    0x00001414,0x00001415,0x00001406,0x00001407,
    0x00001400,0x00071400,0x00061400,0x00151400,
    0x00141400,0x00141500,0x00140600,0x00140700,
    0x00140606,0x00140611,0x00140615,0x00140610,
    0x00140614,0x00100614,0x00150614,0x00110614,
    0x00060614,0x00061114,0x00061514,0x00061014,
    0x00061414,0x00061410,0x00061415,0x00061411,
    0x00061406,0x00111406,0x00151406,0x00101406,
    0x00141406,0x00141006,0x00141506,0x00141106,
    0x00141414,0x00141416,0x00141410,0x00141412,
    0x00141414,0x00121414,0x00101414,0x00161414,
    0x00141414,0x00141614,0x00141014,0x00141214,
    0x00141414,0x00141412,0x00141410,0x00141416,
    0x00141414,0x00161414,0x00101414,0x00121414,
    0x00141414,0x00141214,0x00141014,0x00141614,
    0x00100000,0x00100004,0x00100000,0x00100004,
    0x00100010,0x00040010,0x00000010,0x00040010,
    0x00000010,0x00000410,0x00000010,0x00000410,
    0x00001010,0x00001004,0x00001000,0x00001004,
    0x00001000,0x00041000,0x00001000,0x00041000,
    0x00101000,0x00100400,0x00100000,0x00100400,
    0x00100000,0x00100002,0x00100004,0x00100006,
    0x00100010,0x00060010,0x00040010,0x00020010,
    0x00000010,0x00000210,0x00000410,0x00000610,
    0x00001010,0x00001006,0x00001004,0x00001002,
    0x00001000,0x00021000,0x00041000,0x00061000,
    0x00101000,0x00100600,0x00100400,0x00100200,
    0x00100303,0x00100304,0x00100305,0x00100307,
    0x00100310,0x00070310,0x00050310,0x00040310,
    0x00030310,0x00030410,0x00030510,0x00030710,
    0x00031010,0x00031007,0x00031005,0x00031004,
    0x00031003,0x00041003,0x00051003,0x00071003,
    0x00101003,0x00100703,0x00100503,0x00100403,
    0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,
    0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class _vgapal_init_class
        {
public: _vgapal_init_class();
        } vgapal_init_class;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_vgapal_init_class::_vgapal_init_class()
        {
        int i;
        BYTE a;
        union { unsigned int dd; BYTE db[4]; } c;
        for (i=0;i<256;i++)
            {
            c.dd=vgapal[i];
            c.dd=c.dd<<2;
            a      =c.db[0];
            c.db[0]=c.db[2];
            c.db[2]=      a;
            vgapal[i]=c.dd;
            }
        }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- end. ------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Now back to your question about blending by dithering**

Blending is merging of 2 images of the same resolution together by some amount (weights).  So each pixel color is computed like this:

```
color = w0*color0 + w1*color1;
```

where `color?` are pixels in source images and `w?` are weights where all weights together sum up to 1:

```
w0 + w1 = 1;
```

here example:

- [Draw tbitmap with scale and alpha channel faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54205309/2521214)

and preview (the dots are dithering from my GIF encoder):

[image: Blending]

**But Blending by dithering is done differently.** Instead of Blending colors we use some percentage of pixels from one image and others from the second one. So:

```
if (Random()<w0) color = color0;
 else            color = color1;
```

Where `Random()` returns pseudo random number in range `<0,1>`. As you can see no combinig of colors is done simply you just chose from which image you copy the pixel... Here preview:

[image: Blending by dithering]

Now the dots are caused by the blending by dithering as the intensities of the images are very far away of each other so it does not look good but if you dither relatively similar images (like your shadow maps layers) the result should be good enough (with almost no performance penalty).

To speed up this its usual to precompute the `Random()` outputs for some box (8x8, 16x16 , ...) and use that for whole image (its a bit blocky but that is sort of used as a fun effect ...). This way it can be done also branchlessly (if you store pointers to source images instead of random value).  Also it can be done fully on integers (withou fixed precision) if the weights are integers for example `<0..255>` ...

Now to make cascade/transition from `image0` to `image1` or what ever just simply do something like this:

```
for (w0=1.0;w0>=0.0;w0-=0.05)
 {
 w1=1.0-w0;
 render blended images;
 Sleep(100);
 }
render image1;
```

Comment: `its a bit blocky but that is sort of used as a fun effect ...`
Isn't this pattern is more than a "fun effect"? As far as I understand if we were to dither grayscale to black or white then if we had the bayer matrix ordered in any other way then consecutive numbers with the largest difference between them our eye will not perceive from far the original color without these unique pattern that are eyes sums up and average to get the original color isn't it?
Also tried to blend using a bayer 8x8 matrix but the result doesn't look promising I'll edit the  op.

Comment: @Jorayen shape of the pattern is more or less irrelevant to human eye color perception (randomized dots are used mainly to avoid align and or interference patterns that would be perceived immediately you know some grainy dots you spot only if you look for them). What matters is if you have 8x8 box you got 64 pixels which limits your alpha channels to 64 possible shades/levels. If you want more precise alpha you need bigger box. The fun effect I was writing about was more about transition between images on slideshows, websites, games etc ...

Comment: @Jorayen after zooming your image its clear your matrix and or dithering is not randomized and the interference patters occur we perceive as a texture property ... not sure if GLSL have any usable PRNG people tent to fake it from fragment and or texture coordinates but I would probably use CPU side precomputed [white noise texture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29296619/2521214) instead ... if no PRNG is at disposal

Comment: @Jorayen However why are you not blending the maps together by the standard blending? that is more GLSL friendly than dithering method as you do not have fragment static variable possible in GLSL (at least to my knowledge) ... there would be no seems ...

Comment: @Jorayen from a quick look at your code ` int(mod(gl_FragCoord.x, 8));` is your PRNG and its not working as should ... what is the range of your  `gl_FragCoord` ? if `<-1,+1>`  or `<0,1>` it will not work properly ... as a quick fix try  `int(mod(1234.5678*gl_FragCoord.x, 8));`

Comment: no `gl_FragCoord` is in the range of `<0.5,800.5` on the x axis and `<0.5, 600.5` on the y axis if I defined the view port size to 800x600 pixels. Also I have a blending method of using glsl `mix` function but I want to try dithering since it let you sample only one map if possible and not two. (I know in my code sample I sample both anyway but it can be changed)

Comment: @Jorayen do you know the Blend ratio coefficients (alphas)?

Comment: not sure I understand what are the blend ratio coefficients?

Comment: @Jorayen the weights ... what you are doing is 'image = image0*alpha  + (1-alpha)*image1' the alpha is what i asked. From that you kould rewrite the dither to avoid usage of the matrix and have much better statistical properties or numeric stability... I think its `u_CascadeBlend` what range it is?

Comment: I'm having hard time understanding what are the weights you're talking about in the way I've implemented it with the threshold matrix. `u_CascadeBlend` is in the range of `<0.0, 1.0>`

Comment: @Jorayen Blending is always combining 2 or more images together and the ratio (or probability) how much of each image goes to final output is called weight ... or alpha ... does not matter which method of blending you use the purpose is the same...  Try this: `threshold=mod(3.5*gl_FragCoord.x+7.1*gl_FragCoord.y, 100)*0.01;` instead of the matrix stuff ...

Comment: Yea but I'm not trying to blend per se more like choosing between the shadow maps like you've written about without the weights. The desired effect should look like here more or less:
https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/custom-srp/directional-shadows/
in the Dithered Transition section.

Comment: @Jorayen you are using weights you just do not see it ... the `u_CascadeBlend` is the probability and also the weight (its the same thing) ...  the `threshold` is your random value scaled by the weight ... generated from fragment position (as PRNG Seed) and bunch of math (`mod`) that creates random integers that you use to peek the predefined probability distribution of the switching between individual source images (`indexMatrix8x8`) ... that is how I see it at least ... Its just a workaround for missing PRNG in GLSL

Comment: I see, this explanation is now connecting the dots for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the dither blend to work in my code as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NR_LIGHT_SPACE; i++) {
        if (fs_in.v_FragPosClipSpaceZ <= u_CascadeEndClipSpace[i])
        {
            float fade = fadedShadowStrength(fs_in.v_FragPosClipSpaceZ, 1.0 / u_CascadeEndClipSpace[i], 1.0 / u_CascadeBlend);
            if (fade < 1.0) {
                int x = int(mod(gl_FragCoord.x, 8));
                int y = int(mod(gl_FragCoord.y, 8));
                float threshold = (indexMatrix8x8[(x + y * 8)] + 1) / 64.0;
                if (fade < threshold)
                {
                    shadow = isInShadow(fs_in.v_FragPosLightSpace[i + 1], normal, lightDirection, i + 1) * u_ShadowStrength;
                }
                else
                {
                    shadow = isInShadow(fs_in.v_FragPosLightSpace[i], normal, lightDirection, i) * u_ShadowStrength;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                shadow = isInShadow(fs_in.v_FragPosLightSpace[i], normal, lightDirection, i) * u_ShadowStrength;
            }
            break;
        }
}
```

First check if we're close to the cascade split by a fading factor taking into account frag position clip space and the end of the cascade clip-space with `fadedShadowStrength` (I use this function for normal blending between cascade to know when to start blending, basically if blending factor `u_CascadeBlend` is set to `0.1` for example then we blend when we're atleast 90% into the current cascade (z clip space wise).

Then if we need to fade (`if (fade <1.0)`) I just compare the fade factor to the threshold from the matrix and choose shadow map accordingly.
Results:
[image]